How to create Archive for VisionOS app - Invalid Run Destination
I have created an archive for both iOS and MacOS versions of my app by doing the the following steps

Destinations select Build / Any Mac (Mac Catalyst, arm64, x86_64) or iOS Device
Product > Archive

However when doing the same steps for VisionOS I get an error Invalid Run Destination I have selected both destinations, visionOS Simulator and Build any VisionOS simulator device (arm64, x86_64)
Tried both:

Should work for:

I am able to run the app and test, now I would like to upload to AppStoreConnect for TestFlight and App Store submission.

Xcode: v15.3
MacOS: Sonoma 14.5
Build options available:


You can upload a simulator build to the App Store.

@Paulw11 When I select both destinations, visionOS Simulator and Build any VisionOS simulator device (arm64, x86_64) and then archive I get this error. Let me know if I have misunderstood

You have to select any visionOS device, not any visionOS simulator

I have selected Build, Any visionOS simulator device (arm64, x86_64) and still get the issue, I have added image to question for reference

for the third time, not simulator!  Select "Any visionOS Device (Designed for iPad, arm64)"

@Paulw11 When I do that the archive is listed as iOS, and on App Store Connect it does not come up as a build for the VisionOS app

it sounds like you haven't created a visionOS target in your Xcode project.  You have an iOS app that you are also making available for visionOS.  There are two ways of getting your app onto visionOS.  The first is to simply make your iOS app available - This is the approach you are currently taking.  The second is to create a specific visionOS app and publish that on the visionOS store.

I followed the guidelines here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/visionos/bringing-your-app-to-visionos

Yes, so you are bringing your existing iPad app to vision iOS. You build an iOS app and then make it available for visionOS devices in App Store Connect.

You need to select "Any visionOS Device (Designed for iPad, arm64)" before running the "Archive" action. If you try to archive against a simulator destination, you're going to get the error you mentioned.
